# J4. Table class in controller

Tags: joomla-4.x, jtable

I can't get Table class to work in a controller. I try to get the data of a record in a table but I always get

> 0 Call to a member function load() on bool

Is it possible to use the Table class in a controller? What could be omitting?

**administrator/components/com_aaprueba/src/Table/EspaciosTable.php**

```
namespace Sfi\Component\Aaprueba\Administrator\Table;

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use \Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;
use \Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver;

class EspaciosTable extends Table
{
    public function __construct(DatabaseDriver $db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__sfi_es_espacios', 'id', $db);
    }
}
```

**components/com_aaprueba/src/Controller/EspaciosController.php**

```
namespace Sfi\Component\Aaprueba\Site\Controller;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\FormController;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;

class EspaciosController extends FormController
{
    public function getEspacio()
    {
        Table::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_aaprueba/src/Table');
        $table = Table::getInstance('Espacios', 'Table', array());
        $id = 2;
        $table->load($id);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MVC factory. `Joomla\CMS\Table\Table::addIncludePath()` call is not needed in J4 style components.

```
$table = $this->factory->createTable('Espacios', 'Administrator');
```

Comment: Thanks!. Out of model or controller like helpers or Ajax controllers, I found @Sharky solution how help me: `$table = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_foo')->getMVCFactory()->createTable('user', 'Administrator');`